# Relationship between regular value and regular point.

Tags: differential-geometry

Now let say I have a map $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and I have its differential at a point $p\in S$ denoted by $df_p$ mapping tangent vector of a curve in $S$ to the tangent vector of a curve in $\mathbb{R}$. (which is a point in $\mathbb{R}$). The book by do Carmo's state that a point $q\in\mathbb{R}$ is a regular value if all of the points $p\in S$ of its preimage satisfies $df_p\neq 0$ 
Also, I found on the internet that a point on the surface $S$ is the regular point if all its tangent vector at that point forms a tangent plane.

Is there any relationship between the regular points and the regular values?

Comment: Hi! Maybe you mean "....of its preimage satisfies $df_p\neq 0$..."?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have edited it.

Comment: I don't understand the definition you gave for a regular point, where did you find it? I have another definition that is: $p\in S$ is a regular point for a smooth function between manifolds $f:S\rightarrow T$ if $df_p$ is surjective.

Comment: http://www.grad.hr/geomteh3d/Plohe/plohe1_eng.html

I found it from here.

Comment: The definition in the site is a different thing: It does not speak about smooth manifold formally and is not what you search. The concept of regular point and regular value is related to a function $f:S\rightarrow R$ between smooth manifolds. In particular a point $p\in S$ is a regular point if $df_p$ is surjective; a point $q\in R$ is a regular value if for all $x\in f^{-1}(q)$, $x$ is a regular point. As you can see, these definitions include the case in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of regular point and regular value are related to a function $f:S\rightarrow R$ between smooth manifolds.

In particular

- a point $p\in S$ is a *regular point* if $df_p$ is surjective;
- a point $q\in R$ is a *regular value* if for all $x\in f^{-1}(q)$,
  $x$ is a regular point.

As you can see, these definitions include the case in your question.

Comment: Can I say also, a point $p\in S$ is a regular point if $dfp≠0$? And also an extra thing, we say a point $p\in S$ is a singular point if $dfp≡0$ right? Another question would be, does regular point $p\in S$ ensures the injectivity of $df_p$?

Comment: @LingMinHao
(1) In general the anwer is no. The two notions coincides when $R$ is a $1$-dimensional manifold (for example when $R=\mathbb R$) since the differential is not surjective if and only if it is $0$.

(2) Here again there is a definition of _critical point_: $p$ is a critical point for $f$ if $df_p$ is NOT surjective; As example for this two questions take the smooth map $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ s.t. $f(x,y)= (x,0)$. Then every point $p\in \mathbb R^2$ is a critical point.

Comment: @LingMinHao
(3) In general the answer is no. Take $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$, s.t. $f(x,y)=x$. Here all points are regular but their differentials are not injective.